# Join 2 Arrays with Delimiter in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two NSMutable arrays say A and B. I want to join the 1st element A1 with B1, A2 with B2 and so on. How can i accomplish this. I have tried componentsJoinedByString method, but it works only for 1 array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in method for that, so you would need to use a loop:

```
// Find how many items we need to join
int top = min(A.count, B.count);
// Prepare the result array
NSMutableArrat *res = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0 ; i != top ; i++) {
    [res addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", A[i], B[i]]];
    // Here is the delimiter ---------------------^^^
}
```

The above code uses the new array syntax; you can use `objectAtIndex:` if you prefer.

Comment: I was suppose to follow similar approach. But then i thought there might be some inbuilt methods that i am not aware of . Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", [A objectAtIndex:index], [B objectAtIndex:index]];
```